# Create universal framework with static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, static-libraries

I have created a framework which contains a static library inside:

[image]

The frameworks works in device, but simulator is started giving errors.
Then i try to make the universal framework using script given here:

https://medium.com/@nishantnitb/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a

Now i can able to see universal framework:

[image]

But still not able to run in simulator, this framework is working in real device.
It is giving error _OBJC_CLASS_$someclass", referenced from: in simulator.

Should i need to make universal to static library as well?If yes how can i add in my universal frameworks.

I hope i am able to explain my requirement.
correct me if i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!!!

**I Got the problem above, my framework in universal but my static library is not universal.**

I am trying to make my static lib universal but not getting success.
**Any one know how to make both(my framework and static lib)universal**

Comment: Does the build show any errors? Are you using pods in your project?

Comment: Yes , in simulator only it is giving error.No pod i have created framework.

Comment: "_OBJC_CLASS_$someclass", referenced from: like that

Comment: Please use lipo -info command to check the supported architectures for your framework. Looks like it was not built correctly for simulator.

Comment: sorry,but  i have no idea about lipo -info, where should i put lipo -info comand?

Comment: Use a terminal. You have to make sure the framework is built correctly for all the platforms

Comment: thanks @manishg i got the info: Architectures in the fat file: libProtocolBuffers.a are: armv7 i386 arm64.

Comment: How can i give my lib support to architecture x86_64

Comment: Do you have the static library built for x86_64 platform? If not, build so if you have the code. Then use ‘lipo -create’ to merge the static libraries to a single multi arch fat library