# iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:763:2: error: Unsupported architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture

I am creating a universal framework by taking reference from https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/how-to-create-universal-static-library-ios/  but while running i am getting 
Shell Script Invocation Error like below :

[image]

here is my configuration:

[image]

[image]

Here is my script for creating universal framework:
    # define output folder environment variable
    UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

```
# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 2. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

echo "Universal library can be found here:"
echo ${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
```

The above script is working in my another framework.but in current project it is giving error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create universal framework with static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654530/create-universal-framework-with-static-library)

Comment: both are related but totally diffrent